# Snow Leopard Server in Parallels with Retina MacBook Pro (No DVD Drive)

Tags: snow-leopard, macbook-pro, osx-server, parallels-desktop

I'm trying to install Snow Leopard Server in a Virtual Machine in my Retina MacBook Pro, but I was unable to do it since I don't have a DVD drive in my MacBook.

I've done an DMG file from the original Snow Leopard Server DVD but, it has no effect, since Parallels cannot install Snow Leopard Server from a .dmg file.

Any ideas?

PS: I just want to use Rosetta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** I totally read *everything* wrong. My mistake.

You should be able to install Snow Leopard Server by converting your DMG to ISO. See this OS X Daily article for full details:

[Convert DMG to CDR or ISO with Disk Utility](http://osxdaily.com/2012/07/18/convert-dmg-to-cdr-or-iso-with-disk-utility/)

If you'd rather create the ISO directly from the original disk, [that's possible too](https://superuser.com/a/85991).

Comment: It's Snow Leopard Server, and it's supported.

Comment: @ViníciusFerrão You're absolutely right! What a blunder on my part. I've updated my answer. Thanks for the heads up.